# Creating Simple Hangman Game in js and Can't get if statement read correctly

Tags: javascript, if-statement

In the code below, I can not get the code to execute if the players guess of a letter is not in the secret word chosen.  I have it set so when the submit button is hit, we first check to see if the letter guessed is in the puzzle word, if it is the letter is turned over, then I am trying to say if it is not in the word take a life away from the player.  I've tried several ways but can not get the program to read the second if statement correctly.

```
submit.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log("clicked");
    usedLetters.innerHTML += playersLetter.value + ' '

    for(i=0; i<checkWord.length; i++){
      console.log(wordLife)

      if(playersLetter.value == (checkWord[i])){
        console.log('in if#1')
        console.log(playersLetter.value)
        var answerLetter = document.getElementsByClassName('letter')[i]
        answerLetter.innerHTML = playersLetter.value
        wordLife--
      }
    }

  function scoreLetter(value){// To check if the letter is actually in the word
  for(let i = 0; i < checkWord.length; i++){
    if(value == (checkWord[i])){
      return true
    }else {
      return false
    }
  }
}
console.log('read function')

 if(scoreLetter(playersLetter.value) == false){
   console.log('in 2nd if')
   playerLife--

console.log(playerLife)
}    
})
```

Comment: Post a working code snippet demonstrating your problem.

Comment: Where is scoreLetter defined? It seems something wrong within that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scoreLetter function is wrong, you are only checking the first letter and returning false if the value in not in the first position. 
   Try this ... to check if the letter is in the array

```
 function scoreLetter(value){
      return (checkWord.indexOf(value) === -1) ? false : true;
  }
```

Comment: You da man jonhid.  That worked perfectly.  Thanks to everyone else as well.